# Get disk space information from multiple remote windows servers

Tags: windows, remote-server, windows-server

I am trying to make a tool that would login to multiple remote windows servers and get their drive details and display them under one window.

Possible command that I am looking forward to execute in the remote server is `wmic logicaldisk get size,freespace,caption`. I intend to get the output of this command and display it.

I have remote server hostname and IP, username and password.

How do I connect to these remote servers and execute the command?

Comment: The [#1 hit for "WMIC"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb742610.aspx) has the answer. `wmic /node:SERVER1 printer list status` runs the `printer list status` command on the computer named `SERVER1`.

Comment: You should accept user2301394's answer for provide your own.

Answer (score 3):

So, PowerShell is not enabled, which means you need to use a batch file. I would suggest you to try this script. I have found this script and it is working fine.

```
@ECHO OFF
IF "%~1"=="" goto help
IF "%~2"=="" goto help

@SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
@SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

@FOR /F "tokens=1-3" %%n IN ('"WMIC /node:"%1" LOGICALDISK GET Name,Size,FreeSpace | find /i "%2""') DO @SET FreeBytes=%%n & @SET TotalBytes=%%p

@SET /A TotalSpace=!TotalBytes:~0,-9!
@SET /A FreeSpace=!FreeBytes:~0,-10!
@SET /A TotalUsed=%TotalSpace% - %FreeSpace%
@SET /A PercentUsed=(!TotalUsed!*100)/!TotalSpace!
@SET /A PercentFree=100-!PercentUsed!

IF %TotalSpace% LSS 0 goto error

@ECHO Total space: %TotalSpace%GB
@ECHO Free space: %FreeSpace%GB
@ECHO Used space: %TotalUsed%GB
@ECHO Percent Used: %PercentUsed%%%
@ECHO Percent Free: %PercentFree%%%

@SET TotalSpace=
@SET FreeSpace=
@SET TotalUsed=
@SET PercentUsed=
@SET PercentFree=
goto end

:error
echo.
echo *** Invalid server or drive specified ***
echo.
goto help

:help
echo.
echo diskfree.cmd
echo.
echo Queries remote server for free disk space.
echo Specify a MACHINENAME and a drive letter to be queried
echo.
echo Example:   diskfree.cmd MACHINENAME c:
echo.
goto end


:end
```

Comment: There is something wrong with the calcualtions, the value in GB are not correct. They differ from the original values.

Comment: Please paste your output here.

Comment: I have checked the script and found it is calculating as per the byte value. To check, if you right click on drive then you can see the value is almost equal.

Comment: well i spotted the error, this code is simply dividing the bytes value by 1000 to convert to KB and so on instead of using the conventional 1024. Due to this there is a difference in value.

Comment: nice u can use something like @FOR %%A in (%drives%) DO FOR /F "tokens=1-3" %%n IN ('"call diskfree %%A:"') DO IF "%%n" NEQ "Percent" set /a tot%%n=tot%%n + %%p to get system totals.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to issue remote commends with PowerShell but you have to enable PowerShell Remoting. [Here](http://www.howtogeek.com/117192/how-to-run-powershell-commands-on-remote-computers/) is a tutorial that looks ok.

Comment: powershell is not enable in the remote servers. I will need to work with the traditional command promt.